# OpenCV + Python + GigE Vision Camera

Tags: python, opencv

I want to ask if someone have idea if it's possible to implement a VideoCapture using OpenCV+Python and a GigE Vision Camera, I tried with cv2.VideoCapture(0) but I am always obtaining the video of the integrated webcam. I was trying new beta of OpenCV and using Windows

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
 frame = capture.read()
 cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == odd('q'):
  break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try: `print cv2.getBuildInformation()` i'm pretty sure, that the prebuild binaries do not come with support for pvapi or such. you will need the resp. SDK, and rebuild from src

Comment: Ok I obtained that info, as you said PvAPI:NO and GigEVisionSDK:NO, so can you explain me a little bit in detail how I can rebuild from src???? I mean, I have installed the SDK of the camera but I do not know how to do the rebuild. Thanks

Comment: you will need cmake(-gui), the opencv src (and some dependancies, like numpy) and rebuild the [whole thing from scratch](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files).

Comment: you mean creating my own libs???

Comment: yes. build your own opencv libs locally.

Comment: Which brand of camera? Does it have a programming SDK?

Comment: Genie one, I did my own libs using the steps to python + opencv but I am still having the flags mentioned above in NO. Any idea?

Comment: Were you able to make progress?  It seems that there should be one more step to connect to a gige camera ...like specifying the ip address or something.  For ip cameras with a 'stream', people pass the stream address ; cv2.VideoCapture('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') , but i think a gige camera isn't the same as an ip camera; for my pointgrey blackfly gige cam there is no such stream and I get OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file htttp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...

Answer (score 5):

It could be easier to use harvesters for this task. It would give you all the needed flexibility, and it is optimized for GIGE cameras. 
https://github.com/genicam/harvesters

I have been using it for a while, and it looks simple enough and fast enough.

Comment: Vote on this. Note that Harvester is provides you a very intuitive way to manipulate images through OpenCV and is capable of handling not only GigE Vision cameras but also USB3 Vision cameras! You can find the latest coveratge at this page: https://github.com/genicam/harvesters#development-status

Comment: @Doofah Hi can you please link to a sample pythons script that uses harvesters to read GigE vision camera.

Comment: @Ahmed Hi, thank you for your comment. You can find some basic tutorials at the following URL: https://github.com/genicam/harvesters/blob/master/src/harvesters/test/test_tutorials.py

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a way to do so, a german company called Stemmer Imaging developped a Python library for the GenICam standard. That should do the trick. At the moment I am researching for myself to accomplish the same task, and this is what I found:

[Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAom64iNyjQ&feature=emb_title)
as well as this
[Link 2](https://forum.commonvisionblox.com/t/getting-started-with-cvbpy/241).

Personally I was not able to get it working so far, but that should only be a matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use harvesters to do this task.

First you should pip install harvesters and make sure you are using python version 3.6,3.7 or 3.8. Next you should install a GenTL Producer. Matrix Vision producer allows you to use any camera manufacturer. I've had issues with the newest version so test out different versions if you have issue [HERE](http://static.matrix-vision.com/mvIMPACT_Acquire/).

After installing MvGenTLAqcuire.... link the .CTI file and connect to camera with this code.

```
from harvesters.core import Harvester 
h = Harvester()
gentl_file = r"C:\Program Files\MATRIX VISION\mvIMPACT Acquire\bin\x64\mvGenTLProducer.cti"

h.add_file(gentl_file)
ia = h.create(0)
with ia.fetch_buffer() as buffer:
                    component = buffer.payload.components[0]
                    print(buffer.payload.components)
                    _2d = component.data.reshape(component.height,component.width,                                          int(component.num_components_per_pixel))

                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(_2d,cv2.COLOR_BayerRG2RGB)

ia.stop_acquisition()
ia.destroy()
```

Answer (score -5):

Passing another integer value in function  cv2.VideoCapture(int) instead of 0 selects another camera that is connected. example  cv2.VideoCapture(1)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while (True):
 frame = capture.read()
 cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == odd('q'):
  break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: OpenCV: out device of bound (0-0): 1 . .... it thinks there is only one camera.   Not searching for gige cameras on ethernet ports I suspect?  Camera 0 is the laptop camera.