# How to read and grab frame form Gige Hikvision camera in python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, ip, hikvision

I have a Gige camera brand Hikvision scan camera. The model is MV-CA032-10GC.

This camera are using IP address. I already configure the IPv4 and camera work fine using MVS and eBus player.

My problem is how can I read frame directly from camera using python. I try using python-opencv but its not work because i dont have the port of the camera.

Comment: Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484870/2280890) suggest it is easy to use a python library called [harvesters](https://github.com/genicam/harvesters) for this task.